# MySql pivot table or join trouble

Tags: mysql, join, pivot

I have a table, that looks like the following:

```
pkey|ICAO|   Dt     |Tm      |Temp|Dew
0   |KPHL|2014-03-05|00:00:00|46  |32
1   |KPHL|2014-03-05|01:00:00|45  |33
2   |KPHL|2014-03-05|02:00:00|44  |32
3   |KABI|2014-03-05|00:00:00|46  |32
4   |KABI|2014-03-05|01:00:00|46  |32
5   |KABI|2014-03-05|01:00:00|46  |32
6   |KPHL|2014-03-06|00:00:00|47  |32
7   |KPHL|2014-03-06|01:00:00|48  |33
8   |KPHL|2014-03-06|02:00:00|45  |32
9   |KABI|2014-03-06|00:00:00|42  |32
10  |KABI|2014-03-06|01:00:00|44  |32
11  |KABI|2014-03-06|01:00:00|60  |32
```

.. And so on...

I want my query to display all the temps for KPHL, for a date range, say, today, 3/5 and tomorrow 3/6 , and show them side by side... like

```
Tm      | Today | Tomorrow
00:00:00| 46    | 47
01:00:00| 45    | 48
02:00:00| 44    | 45
```

I'm not sure if I need some sort of join, or a pivot table. I've looked quite a bit, but can't find something that mimics what I'm trying to do, and the things that I've tried aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one temp per time, etc.

```
SELECT tm
      ,MAX(CASE dt WHEN '2014-03-05' THEN Temp ELSE NULL END) AS Today
      ,MAX(CASE dt WHEN '2014-03-06' THEN Temp ELSE NULL END) AS Tomorrow
  FROM x
  WHERE dt IN ('2014-03-05', '2014-03-06')
    AND ICAO = 'KPHL'
  GROUP BY tm
  ORDER BY tm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select tm,
       max(case when dt = dt(now()) then temp end) as today,
       max(case when dt = dt(now() + interval 1 day) then temp end) as tomorrow
from table t
where icao = 'KPHL' and
      dt between date(now()) and dt(now() + interval 1 day)
group by tm
order by tm;
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your help. When running the code as is, I received an error, I assume because dt(now) doesn't resolve. I changed the dt(now()) references to date(now) and I'm up and running.